# return decimal value in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have following method in repository project , and I'm trying to get that value via web api,

**Method**

```
    public decimal findBookPrice(int book_id)
    {
        var bookprice = (
                        from r in context.Books
                        where r.Book_Id == book_id
                        select r.Price
                        ).FirstOrDefault();

        return bookprice;

    }
```

**Book Class**

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Book_Title { get; set; }

    [DataType("decimal(16 ,3")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

}

**Web API method**

```
    // GET: api/BookPrice/3  

    [ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int id)
    {
        decimal bookprice = db.findBookPrice(id);

        return Ok(bookprice);
    }
```

but once I direct to url which is http://localhost:13793/api/BookPrice/2

I'm getting following output not the decimal value

[image]

Comment: You'd better return a response type of either XML or JSON then deserialize the response on your client application.

Comment: @Ephraim I'm new to this web api , can you show me the way to do it ?

Comment: There has to be an issue with the routing, regardless of the decimal type in the model. Is your WebAPIController named ´BookPriceController´ as well ?

Comment: @rboe No this web api method inside `BooksWithAuthersController` controller class

Comment: Then try the URL http://localhost:13793/api/BooksWithAuthers/2

Comment: Definitely a routing issue, not related to the return type. Anyway, when you expect only one item from a linq query, use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`. It's clearer and it lets you find issues sooner.

Comment: @Andrew As you said I changed my Method `var bookprice = ().FirstOrDefault();` to `var bookprice = ().SingleOrDefault();` but nothing changed :(

Comment: can you please expose your WebApiConfig.cs class file!

Comment: @kez, mine was just a suggestion for clarity, it wasn't related to this issue. If for some reason that linq returned many results, you would have a problem and with `FirstOrDefault` you would not discover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown error message is caused by a routing problem. The ASP.NET MVC framework was not able to find the right controller or action for the URL

```
http://localhost:13793/api/BookPrice/2
```

The default routing rule in ASP.NET MVC takes `BookPrice`and tries to find the `BookPriceController`. As you stated in your comment, the action is in a `BooksWithAuthersController`. Therefore the URL has to be (if you want to use the default routing rule):

```
http://localhost:13793/api/BooksWithAuthers/2
```

Have a look at [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) if you want to read more about this topic.

EDIT:

Looking at the whole [controller code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/Gp5ek) you will find the two action methods called `GetBooksWithAuthersById` and `GetBooksPriceById`. Because both start with `get` and have got the same parameter list (`int id`), the ASP.NET MVC framework has got two possible action methods for the URL `/api/BooksWithAuthors/2`. To solve this ambiguity you can give the `GetBooksPriceById` action a separate route via the `[Route]` annotation.

Like in this slightly adjusted BooksWithAuthersController:

```
 public class BooksWithAuthersController : ApiController
 {                   
    [ResponseType(typeof(BookWithAuther))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBooksWithAuthersById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
   
    [ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
    [Route("api/bookswithauthers/{id}/price")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In order get the price of a book, the URL `http://localhost:13793/api/BooksWithAuthers/2/price` will return the decimal value.

Comment: please look at this whole code , first two methods working fine , last decimal return not working here, can you look at whole code here https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/Gp5ek

Comment: @kez: I have extended my answer to reflect the ambiguous action methods.

Comment: thnks for your answer , how this `price` identify as decimal type in URL , or is it using as an unique identifier ?

Comment: @kez: You are welcome. The ´price´is only to have different URL's. You can name as you like. It has nothing to do with the decimal type.

Comment: if its not a bother to can I ask another related question here ?

Comment: can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526334/method-overloading-in-web-api