# multiple parameters passing with method overloading in WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, overloading

I have following methods in Repository Class

```
    public class LibraryRepository : IBookRepository
    {
        LibraryContext context = new LibraryContext();

        public decimal findBookPrice(int book_id)
        {
            var bookprice = (
                            from r in context.Books
                            where r.Book_Id == book_id
                            select r.Price
                            ).FirstOrDefault();

            return bookprice;

        }

        public decimal findBookPrice(int book_id, string bookname)
        {
            var bookprice = (
                             from book in context.Books
                             where book.Book_Id == book_id & book.Book_Title == bookname
                             select book.Price
                             ).FirstOrDefault();

            return bookprice;

        }  

    }
```

Then I'm trying to get those two methods separately in Web API

```
    public class BooksWithAuthersController : ApiController
    {

        private LibraryRepository db = new LibraryRepository();

        // GET: api/BooksWithAuthers/id/Price  

        [ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
        [Route("api/BooksWithAuthers/{id}/Price")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int id)
        {
            decimal bookprice = db.findBookPrice(id);

            return Ok(bookprice);
        }

        // GET: api/BooksWithAuthers/id,name/Price

        [ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
        [Route("api/BooksWithAuthers/{id,name}/Price")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int id,string name)
        {
            decimal bookprice = db.findBookPrice(id,name);

            return Ok(bookprice);
        }
    }
```

Here first method working fine, but How can I handle scenario with multiple parameters

[image]

Comment: Is the comma separated thing {id,name} is even possible ? Any references to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this `{id,name}` is even possible.You are getting the exception because routing module is reading 5,test as single attribute and is not able serialize it to int for method

`public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int id)`

You need to change your methods as below considering nullable types (int?) and also change the route

```
[ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
[Route("api/BooksWithAuthers/{id}/Price")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int? id)
{
   decimal bookprice = db.findBookPrice(id);
   return Ok(bookprice);
}


[ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
[Route("api/BooksWithAuthers/{id}/{name}/Price")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBooksPriceById(int? id,string name = null)
{
    decimal bookprice = db.findBookPrice(id,name);

    return Ok(bookprice);
}
```

Reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: I tried your approach but here getting exception once id==null http://imgur.com/a/pTPLI

Answer (score 0):

Set your parameter as a `nullable` type like below:

```
public class LibraryRepository : IBookRepository, I
    {
        LibraryContext context = new LibraryContext();

        public decimal findBookPrice(int book_id=0)
        {
            var bookprice = (
                            from r in context.Books
                            where r.Book_Id == book_id
                            select r.Price
                            ).FirstOrDefault();

            return bookprice;

        }

        public decimal findBookPrice(int book_id=0, string bookname=null)
        {
            var bookprice = (
                             from book in context.Books
                             where book.Book_Id == book_id & book.Book_Title == bookname
                             select book.Price
                             ).FirstOrDefault();

            return bookprice;

        }  

    }
```

and set a condition simply to check `nullable` parameter like below:

```
if(book_id!=0)
{
    // do your logic here
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookname))
{
   // do your logic here
}
```

Hope this will help you

Thanks